# File being shown as a directory, not a file?

Tags: java, android

I'm in the process of making an Android application that creates a new file when a button is pressed. I'm using the following code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         +File.separator
         +"myDirectory" //folder name
         +File.separator
         +"myFile.png"); //file name
file.mkdirs();
```

However, `myFile.png` is actually being displayed as a directory and not a .png file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of  `file.mkdirs();`  **mkdirs()** - is used for making directory by filename given file object's parameter, If you want to make a file make IO operation for writing in a file,

In your case: to make a directory,

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     +File.separator
     +"myDirectory" //folder name
     +File.separator
     +"myFile.png"); //file name
   file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

This make a myDirectory folder in external storage.

Answer (score 2):

According to [its documentation `File.mkdirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) "creates the directory named by the trailing filename of this file".

In other words: you *explictly* create a directory named `myFile.png`. If that's *not* what you want, then you *probably* want to do `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.mkdirs()
```

the above code will create the new directories.

To create the file

```
try{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         +File.separator
         +"myDirectory" //folder name
         +File.separator
         +"myFile.png"); //file name

    myFile.createNewFile();
    OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    filoutputStream.write(b);
    filoutputStream.flush();
    filoutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // handler exception
}
```